# How may I choose subscriber while publishing event using EventAggregator in Calirburn Micro?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

How may I choose subscriber while publishing event using EventAggregator in Calirburn Micro?

I have four subscribers for some particular message at single time but I want to send notification to one of them while publishing the message. Subscribers are generic here and I'm interested only in appropriate(one) subscriber suitable for the publisher type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My two suggestions would be:

- Define a new kind of Event that only the target you're interested in gets subscribed to, or...
- Let each subscriber decide if that message is for them or not (by including something in the Arguments that helps them discriminate, like an ID or some other identifying property)

Those are the only two correct options for a Publisher-Subscriber pattern, IIRC.

Comment: Thanks. I can not create new Event or Messgae because purpose is same. Keeping ID may help but it requires alot of changes to get implemented in entire application.

Is there not anyother way defined in Event Aggregator itself?